# Getting Number of weeks in a Month from a Datetime Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table called FcData and the data looks like:

```
Op_Date

2011-02-14 11:53:40.000
2011-02-17 16:02:19.000
2010-02-14 12:53:40.000
2010-02-17 14:02:19.000
```

I am looking to get the Number of weeks in That Month from Op_Date. So I am looking for output like:

```
 Op_Date                       Number of Weeks

    2011-02-14 11:53:40.000       5   
    2011-02-17 16:02:19.000       5
    2010-02-14 12:53:40.000       5
    2010-02-17 14:02:19.000       5
```

Comment: What's your rule for how many weeks there are in a month?

Comment: @AakashM I need to extract the month from Op_date column and get the number of weeks in that month as output.

Comment: Yes, I get that. What I want to know is your rule for getting the result `5` from the input `February 2010`.

Comment: @AakashM The rule is if any of the day from that particular month is part of the week then i would count as 1 for example: Feb 28 2010 comes on Sunday But I would still Count as 1

Comment: Actually, I'm more curious how you're getting **5** weeks out of **28** days.  Even with shifting start-of-week and how many days constiture the start-of-year/week, you should still end up with only **4** weeks.  Unless I'm missing something somewhere?

Comment: @X-Zero Feb 28 2010 comes on Sunday But I would still Count as 1 even though it is only 1 day that is how I got 5 weeks

Comment: @Peter That's exactly what I'm getting at - there's only **4** Sundays in February.  If you count your weeks starting with Sunday, then that needs to apply for every month; under the given criteria, the week containing February 1st, 2010, actually belongs to _January_, not February.  This is usually important for financial and other analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to get the number of week for ONE specific date. Replace `GetDate()` by your date:

```
declare @dt date = cast(GetDate() as date);
declare @dtstart date =  DATEADD(day, -DATEPART(day, @dt) + 1, @dt);
declare @dtend date = dateadd(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @dtstart));

WITH dates AS (
     SELECT @dtstart ADate
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, t.ADate) 
       FROM dates t
      WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, t.ADate) <= @dtend
)
SELECT top 1 DatePart(WEEKDAY, ADate) weekday, COUNT(*) weeks
  FROM dates d
  group by DatePart(WEEKDAY, ADate)
  order by 2 desc
```

Explained: the CTE creates a result set with all dates for the month of the given date. Then we query the result set, grouping by week day and count the number of occurrences. The max number will give us how many weeks the month overlaps (premise: if the month has 5 Mondays, it will cover five weeks of the year).

**Update**

Now, if you have multiple dates, you should tweak accordingly, joining your query with the `dates` CTE.

Comment: This will of course not get the results the OP expects - there are only 4 of any specific day of the week in a non-leap year February.  Thus, it will generate a maximum week-number of 4, not 5 as requested.

Answer (score 2):

This page has some good functions to figure out the last day of any given month: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/get-last-day-of-month.aspx

Just wrap the output of that function with a `DATEPART(wk, last_day_of_month)` call. Combining it with an equivalent call for the 1st-day-of-week will let you get the number of weeks in that month.

Comment: DATEPART result is influenced by @@DATEFIRST setting. Different SET DATEFIRST values => different DATEPART results => different WK num.

Comment: Depending on use case, this is either completely worrisome or completely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on it, might have missed something.

In Linq:

```
from u in TblUsers
let date = u.CreateDate.Value
let firstDay = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1)
let lastDay = firstDay.AddMonths(1)
where u.CreateDate.HasValue
select Math.Ceiling((lastDay - firstDay).TotalDays / 7)
```

And generated SQL:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 1
DECLARE @p1 Int = 1
DECLARE @p2 Float = 7
-- EndRegion
SELECT CEILING(((CONVERT(Float,CONVERT(BigInt,(((CONVERT(BigInt,DATEDIFF(DAY, [t3].[value], [t3].[value2]))) * 86400000) + DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, [t3].[value], [t3].[value2]), [t3].[value]), [t3].[value2])) * 10000))) / 864000000000) / @p2) AS [value]
FROM (
    SELECT [t2].[createDate], [t2].[value], DATEADD(MONTH, @p1, [t2].[value]) AS [value2]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t1].[createDate], CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(NCHAR(2), DATEPART(Month, [t1].[value])) + ('/' + (CONVERT(NCHAR(2), @p0) + ('/' + CONVERT(NCHAR(4), DATEPART(Year, [t1].[value]))))), 101) AS [value]
        FROM (
            SELECT [t0].[createDate], [t0].[createDate] AS [value]
            FROM [tblUser] AS [t0]
            ) AS [t1]
        ) AS [t2]
    ) AS [t3]
WHERE [t3].[createDate] IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx you can only get the current week in the year, not what that month returns.

Answer (score 0):

There may be various approaches to implementing the idea [suggested by @Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475845/getting-number-of-weeks-in-a-month-from-a-datetime-column/7475919#7475919). Here's one, where no UDFs are used but the first and the last days of month are calculated directly:

```
WITH SampleData AS (
  SELECT CAST('20110214' AS datetime) AS Op_Date
  UNION ALL SELECT '20110217'
  UNION ALL SELECT '20100214'
  UNION ALL SELECT '20100217'
  UNION ALL SELECT '20090214'
  UNION ALL SELECT '20090217'
),
MonthStarts AS (
  SELECT
    Op_Date,
    MonthStart = DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(Op_Date), Op_Date)
    /* alternatively: DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Op_Date), 0) */
  FROM FcData
),
Months AS (
  SELECT
    Op_Date,
    MonthStart,
    MonthEnd = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, MonthStart))
  FROM FcData
)
Weeks AS (
  SELECT
    Op_Date,
    StartWeek = DATEPART(WEEK, MonthStart),
    EndWeek   = DATEPART(WEEK, MonthEnd)
  FROM MonthStarts
)
SELECT
  Op_Date,
  NumberOfWeeks = EndWeek - StartWeek + 1
FROM Weeks
```

All calculations could be done in one SELECT, but I chose to split them into steps and place every step in a separate CTE so it could be seen better how the end result was obtained.

Answer (score 0):

You can get number of weeks per month using the following method.

```
Datepart(WEEK,
         DATEADD(DAY,
                 -1,
                 DATEADD(MONTH,
                         1,
                         DATEADD(DAY,
                                 1 - DAY(GETDATE()),
                                 GETDATE())))
         -
         DATEADD(DAY,
                 1 - DAY(GETDATE()),
                 GETDATE())
         +1
         )
```

Comment: Very Sort Line: DATEDIFF(week, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0), GETDATE()) +1

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can get accurate amount of weeks:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET @date = GETDATE()
SELECT ROUND(cast(datediff(day, dateadd(day, 1-day(@date), @date), dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(day, 1-day(@date), @date))) AS FLOAT) / 7, 2)
```

With this code for **Sep 2014** you'll get **4.29** which is actually true since there're 4 full weeks and 2 more days.